Ways to prove a problem is hard for a class
If I want to prove that some language $A$ is hard for class $C$, the obvious way is a Karp reduction. You could also show it by finding some subset of $A$ that's hard for $C$.
What other ways are there to show a language is hard for a class?
Sorry for the potentially silly question, I'm just stumped on a problem and want to make sure I'm not overlooking some useful tool.

"You could also show it by finding some subset of $A$ that's hard for $C$." is just wrong, for example if $A = \Sigma^*$ in many cases.

Oops sorry you're right @Nathaniel . I was thinking about the polynomial hierarchy. In that context, could the assertion be corrected if I added the condition that the two languages be defined in terms of the same poly-time relation? For example, SAT is NP-hard "because" 3SAT is NP-hard (obviously there's a better justification but just as an example).

I don't understand your condition. Please define it formally.

Besides Karp reduction, there are several ways to conclude a language is hard for a class such as Cook-Levin theorem, the proof TQBF is PSPACE-hard, etc. There usually are to prove the first hard language so that we could apply Karp reduction for other languages after that.

Thank you for the response! Do you know if the development of new ways to prove hardness is an active area of research? Is there any interest in that, or is it considered superfluous (if not impossible)?

Idk. You should post another question so that other people can answer ít.
